# To say "I like something" in Korean, should I use 내가 or 나는?

Tags: word-usage

Hello everyone I am new in this amazing language while I came from youtube I was watched a video from of Kpop  a singer girl say this word: **내가** that if you looking for its meaning is: I, me, my  [I found that here](https://www.lingq.com/en/learn-korean-online/translate/ko/%EB%82%B4%EA%B0%80/)

I want to say : **I like food** when I wrote that in google translate I found this:

**나는 음식을 좋아한다**

then in this part:**나는** mean me or I whatever then what word should use if I want to say: I like food?

this is the song I am listenig:[twice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAKsZ26SabQ)
  in the min: 1:01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between 는/은 and 가/이 is quite a complicated topic - there is a short answer here: [What are the differences between 는 / 은 and 가 / 이?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-the-differences-between-%EB%8A%94-%EC%9D%80-and-%EA%B0%80-%EC%9D%B4) - but there is a lot more detail to it than that.

A simple answer about your particular case here: 나는 음식을 좋아한다 is the more neutral way to say 'I like food', while 내가 음식을 좋아한다 emphasises the 'I' more: "It's ME who likes food".