# Image Provided - Why is 는 used in only one if the following answers but both are correct?

Tags: translation

In the pictures shown I am learning korean using the app lingodeer and its been great and I understand why things are done alot of the time, but here :

Why is 는 only used in one of the answers when both are basically of the same question?

The Only answer I can think of is because of the ending in Consonant or Vowel Rule?

Thank You in Advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I must say that flashcards do *not* provide sufficient **context** which is particularly important for language learners. You should read multiple sentences that relate to one another rather than trying to understand separate sentences. Books are usually better materials.

For that English sentence, both

> 과일 중에서 수박이 제일 큽니다.

and

> 과일 중에서**는** 수박이 제일 큽니다.

are correct. It is just that the second sentence can mean something more. What is it? Please refer to [this](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/5262/2162) first. I can think of at least two possible answers:

1. The *preceding* sentence was something like this:

> 이 중에서 어느 것이 제일 큰지 아십니까?

or

> 식물 중에서는 세쿼이아가 제일 큽니다.

2. The *following* sentence is going to be something like this:

> 식물 중에서는 세쿼이아가 제일 큽니다.

or

> (그리고) 과일 중에서는 개구리밥이 제일 작습니다.

Without the context, however, there is no way for us to know the speaker's intention.